# Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs

In a **.babelrc** file, I wrote :

```
"plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
  ]
```

In my class, I wrote :

```
class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            ...
        };
        this.changeValue=this.changeValue.bind(this);
        ...
    }
    changeValue = (e) => {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    };
    ...
```

But when I try to import this module, I get :

[image: Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.]

**I don't want to use webpack, it seems very complicated. If there is no other way than webpack, then how should I configure it ?**

Complete project : https://github.com/maifeeulasad/react-mua-login